# Axios on nextjs added slash before query params on GET request

Tags: next.js, axios, crud

I have a typescript nextjs app with the following code:

```
        const ping = axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/quote', {
            params: {
                id: query.quote_id,
            }

        }).then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);
        }
        ).catch((e) => {
            console.log(e)
        });
```

When I look at the insect network tab I see the following:
[image]

When I look at my backend server I see the following request:

`"GET /api/quote/?id=clivd7aiz000lau5mn07td71o HTTP/1.1" 500`

When I do the request on Postman I get the correct behavior. That leads me t believe it's a frontend/client issue.

How can I remove that trailing `/`?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. And it's pretty bizarre.

If I send a request with an invalid `id`, the requests moving forward will have the slash in between the URL and the `?param=value`. When I restart the client the there is no slash between the url and the query params and it works as intended.